# not able to use multiple spinners from a single Arrayadapter having one string array resource

Tags: spinner, android-arrayadapter

i am trying to get 2 string type data from 2 different spinners that are using the same array adapter. I have setup the onItemselectedListener() with switch and case statements. after searching for a while i am pretty sure that the code is correct. Using the adapterView variable,the function is able to determine from which spinner the item was selected. But still something goes wrong and the textView does not change when the item is selected    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {

```
public String[] all = { "dilshad garden", "jhilmil",
        "mansarovar park", "shahadra", "welcome", "seelampur",
        "shastri park", "kashmere gate", "tis hazari", "pul bangash",
        "pratab nagar", "shastri nagar", "inderlok", "kanhiya nagar",
        "netaji subhash place", "kohat enclave", "pitampura",
        "rohini east", "rohini west", "rithala", "jahangirpuri",
        "adarsh nagar", "azadpur", "model town", "gtb nagar",
        "delhi university", "vidhan sabha", "civil lines", "kashmere gate",
        "chandni chowk", "chawri bazar", "new delhi", "rajiv chowk",
        "patel chowk", "centrial secretariat" };


Button route;
Spinner stationFrom, stationTo;
String finalTo, finalFrom, result;
TextView totv,fromtv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    totv=(TextView)findViewById(com.example.delhimetro.R.id.totv);

    stationFrom=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.stationFrom);
    stationTo=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.stationTo);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, all);
    stationFrom.setAdapter(adapter);
    stationTo.setAdapter(adapter);
    stationFrom.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    stationTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    route=(Button)findViewById(R.id.route);
    route.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(arg1.getId()){

    case R.id.stationTo:
        finalTo=stationTo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        totv.setText(finalTo);
        break;

    case R.id.stationFrom:
        finalFrom=stationFrom.getSelectedItem().toString();
        fromtv.setText(finalFrom);
        break;
    }   
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.route:

    break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: sorry for the wrong editing...just ignore the code with the question

Comment: Did you try to put debug prints and find out what's the exact point of failure?